# Only Administrators can use Contact Reference Fields

Tags: contacts

I have a contact reference field that works perfectly as Drupal user 1. It does not work for my non admin users. They have all the permissions for CiviCRM but the select list does not retur results to them. They can see the field and see what admin puts in the field.

This Drupal 7 and Civi 4.5.5.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to provide more detail re the Permissions, but there are specific permissions for

- CiviCRM: access contact reference field
- CiviCRM: access AJAX API

From memory both are required.

Comment: "CiviCRM: access all custom data" ?

Comment: I did not have the AJAX API enabled.